# Wordpress - Grant plugin permission to an Editor

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanted to be able to give a particular user access to an seo plugin (seo ultimate), but not admin level access. I tried adding this to the `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'seo_menu' );
function seo_menu() {
    global $current_user;

    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

    if($user_role == 'editor'){
        add_menu_page( $user_role, $user_role, 10, 'seo', 'seo_options', '/wp-content/plugins/seo-ultimate/plugin/img/icon.png' );
    }
}
```

It was working for me when I switch the if operator from `==` to `!=`, but not for the Editor. My guess is the permission/role checker is in the plugin itself. So I tried messing around in `seo-ultimate.php`, but wasn't sure what part of it did the role validation. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You could see if the SEO plugin integrates with the [User Role Editor plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/screenshots/)

Some plugins will add options for different role capabilities, but others don't. Might be worth a try.

Comment: That didn't quite work. It gave access to be able to activate/edit/delete/install plugins. I was even able to get into a couple of them (eg: contact form 7), but when I tried to access `?page=seo`, I got a message saying I didn't have permission. That's why I think it's within the plugin itself.